# How to test in Python if a built-in function has been called

Tags: python-3.x, sage

I am running a computer programming course that uses Sage and Python, however, I am not an expert programmer myself in Python.  (FYI Sage is an alternative kernel to Python 3, which has a number of efficient packages for abstract algebra compiled in).  I often find myself wanting to assign the students to program some task which Sage can already do built-in to the kernel, and I need to make sure they are not simply calling the built-in functionality.  I am using a program called nbgrader which runs their code and asserts various facts about it to test that it is computing correctly, and can generally run any python command imaginable on the function, it then tests a series of assert commands and if they all pass then they get full credit for the problem.

I have tried to follow tutorials which have me delete the built-in function, or use unit test and mocking to otherwise subvert it.  However, I get errors like:
`can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'sage.structure.element.Matrix` when I try just to delete the built-in matrix multiplication functionality.  Similar errors when I try to mock it.  Is there some clever way for me to either delete or otherwise subvert a built-in function so that it throws an error if they attempt to call it?  Or failing that, can I get python to print to a string a log of all function calls, e.g. so that `sage.structure.element.Matrix.__mult__` would show up in this string if their function when run on some example uses the built-in matrix multiplication functionality?

Comment: Can profiling (https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/tutorial/programming.html#profiling) help?

Comment: Thank you, that was an englightening suggestion.  I do believe profiling would work for me, but the whole process is taking place in an IPython notebook, and my tests need to take place in a single IPython cell.  the %prun command appears to be a console function, so it can only print output to the console, not return a string which I can use in the test cell -- is this a common issue and is there a workaround?

Comment: Ah, but unfortunately, even before I try and figure that question out, if I print the console output of prun, it doesn't recognize sage.structure.element.Matrix.__mult__, it just obfuscates it with a mention of "builtins".

Comment: I think that the issue with "builtins" is that Matrix is a Cython class, not a Python class. If you are using your own copy of Sage, you could modify the `__mult__` method so that it prints a warning when used.